# Best Tika integration on Solr or Nutch

Tags: solr, nutch, apache-tika

Which is the best integration for Apache Tika assuming that I already connected and used  Nutch(2.2.1) + Solr (4.3)?

I understand that Tika can be integrated within Nutch and/or Solr, but which one is the best decision?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What code do you already have?

Comment: No code, only configuration. On one hand I am crawling with nutch and indexing with solr, but my requirement also includes to parse web pdfs, office docs, etc so I need to add Tika. My question is about the best way to do it, Solr side or Nutch side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the Tika plugin with Nutch, Nutch will parse the data for you and will do all the hard work for you.

I would suggest setting it up on Solr as well, you may wish to send documents to Solr via the `curl` command and it would help to have it set up on Solr too.  It comes with little extra configuration and no performance costs:

There is a guide to setting up Tika & extracting request handler [here](http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/setting-up-tika-extracting-request.html)

Comment: If I setup Tika in both sides (Nutch and Solr), exists any way to avoid the double Tika maintenance?

Comment: There is no maintenance. Once the config is set-up thats it, you wont need to change anything anymore.  I have it set-up on both sides and havent needed any maintenance

Answer (score 0):

Apply tika parser in Nutch's parsing phase.